# In breadth first search how is the second node selected?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

Is it selected alphabetically or will I always choose the left node first?
Will I choose `G` first or `B` in the following image? [image: Image of a graph.]

Comment: Would there be a difference? This is a search algorithm, not telepathy.

Comment: In the example i provided, it would be because it can reach the goal directly from S.

Comment: (1) It depends on the implementation, and (2) for a weighted graph, you often need something more sophisticated than a breadth-first search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much answers to your question, more observations:

1. The order that the BFS will go is dependent on it's implementation, the only thing that will be common to all implementations is that they will be breadth first.
2. BFS does not necessarily have anything to do with weighted graphs, you could find or write an algorithm that will scan breadth first with the the order of the scan for each level of the graph being determined by the weight.
3. BFS on this graph would scan S -> [ABG] -> [CD] | [ED] -> G ([possiblities, order depends on implementation], [] | [] means this then that or that then this)